# Tracking/monitoring File/Folder copy activities on windows

Tags: visual-c++

I would like to know if there are any ways to programmatically detect or monitor the file or folder being copied either by copy command(like on command prompt-- copy a b) or by using drag/drop(ctrl+c and ctr+v).
It would be helpful if you could give some pointers( preferably some APIs in vc++)

thanks and regards

Dinakara K

Answer (score 3):

You need to write a file system filter driver: http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/driver/filterdrv/default.mspx

See also the answers to this question: [detect File 'COPY' operation in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576813/detect-file-copy-operation-in-windows)