# Detect file 'COPY' operation in Windows

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi

Say I want to be informed whenever a file copy is launched on my system and get the file name, the destination where it is being copied or moved and the time of copy.

Is this possible? How would you go about it? Should you hook CopyFile API function?

Is there any software that already accomplishes this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Windows has the concept of I/O filters which allow you to intercept all I/O operations and choose to perform additional actions as a result. They are primarily used for A/V type scenarios but can be programmed for a wide variety of tasks. The SysInternals Process Monitor for example uses a I/O filter to see the file level access.

You can view your current filters using MS Filter Manager, (fltmc.exe from a command prompt)

There is a kit to help you write filters, you can get the drivers and develop your own.

http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/driver/filterdrv/default.mspx is a starting place to get in depth info

Answer (score 5):

As there is a .NET tag on this question, I would simply use [`System.IO.FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) that's in the .NET Framework. I'm guessing it is implemented using [the I/O Filters that Andrew mentions in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576813/detect-file-copy-operation-in-windows/1576842#1576842), but I really do not know (nor care, exactly). Would that fit your needs?

Comment: No, it uses FindFirstChangeNotification / ReadDirectoryChangesW, not file system filters.

Comment: @atomice: I'll take your word for it. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 2):

As Andrew says a filter driver is the way to go.

There is no foolproof way of detecting a file copy as different programs copy files in different ways (some may use the CopyFile API, others may just read one file and write out the contents to another themselves). You could try calculating a hash in your filter driver of any file opened for reading, and then do the same after a program finishes writing to a file. If the hashes match you know you have a file copy. However this technique may be slow. If you just hook the CopyFile API you will miss file copies made without that API. Java programs (to name but one) have no access to the CopyFile API.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely impossible as there is no guaranteed central method for performing a copy/move. You could hook into a core API (like CopyFile) but of course that means that you will still miss any copy/move that any application does without using this API.

Maybe you could watch the entire filesystem with IO filters for open files and then just draw conclusions yourself if two files with same names and same filesizes are open at the same time. But that no 100% solution either.

Answer (score 1):

As previously mentioned, a file copy operation can be implemented in various ways and may involve several disk and memory transfers, therefore is not possible to simply get notified by the system when such operation occurs.
Even for the user, there are multiple ways to duplicate content and entire files. Copy commands, "save as", "send to", move, using various tools. Under the hood the copy operation is a succession of read / write, correlated by certain parameters. That is the only way to guarantee successful auditing. Hooking on CopyFile will not give you the copy operations of Total Commander, for example. Nor will it give you "Save as" operations which are in fact file create -> file content moved -> closing of original file -> opening of the new file. Then, things are different when dealing with copy over network, impersonated copy operations where the file handle security context is different than the process security context, and so on. I do not think that there is a straightforward way to achieve all of the above.

However, there is a software that can notify you for most of the common copy operations (i.e. when they are performed through windows explorer, total commander, command prompt and other applications). It also gives you the source and destination file name, the timestamp and other relevant details. It can be found here: http://temasoft.com/products/filemonitor.

Note: I work for the company which develops this product.