# Monitor copy and move operations for file/folder in Java using JNA/JNI

Tags: java, winapi, java-native-interface, jna

I am trying to create an application in Java that is able to monitor copy and move operations for file/folder, similar to the questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576813/detect-file-copy-operation-in-windows/1576842#1576842). This application will monitor all copy and move operations and check whether certain operation is allowed based on the source directory, if it is from confidential directory then the operation is cancelled.

I was thinking to create the app in JNA/JNI but I am not sure where should I start with since I haven't been able to find any similar project in Java. I have found this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776048(v=vs.85).aspx) but it is for CopyHook filter that I am not sure how to implement this in the application.

Any help is appreciated.